# python screenshot send via email

Tags: python, image, sms

A shot in the dark, perhaps, but I am cobbling together a screenshot script (using PIL) and Twilio with SMS to try and capture the screenshot of a webpage and have it sent via SMS (or via email as a second option) to a destination so I can view that image.  So, far, plenty of scripts for sending emails or SMS messages to destinations.  But, nothing with the intermediary step of capturing the screenshot and then sending that screenshot via SMS.  Cannot find anything with Twilio or any other tool to send an image via SMS.

```
import numpy as np 
import cv2 
import pyautogui 
import csv
import time
from time import sleep
from datetime import datetime
import random
import math
import os
import itertools
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException

options = Options()
ua = UserAgent(verify_ssl=False)
userAgent = ua.random
#print('Current UserAgent {}'.format(userAgent))
options.add_argument(f'user-agent={userAgent}')
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
#options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument('--window-size=1920,1080') #this enables clicking things while in headless mode
#driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='chromedriver', options=options)
driver.delete_all_cookies()
searchpage = '[webpage address]'
driver.get(searchpage)
time.sleep(2)

#this takes the screenshot
image = pyautogui.screenshot() 
image = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(image), cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR) 
# writing it to the disk using opencv 
cv2.imwrite("[image name.png]", image)
time.sleep(2)
path = "[name of image]"

# Reading an image in default mode
image = cv2.imread(path)

# Window name in which image is displayed
window_name = 'image'

# closing all open windows
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: How do you determine when the screenshot is to be taken. Do you run the script while you are on the webpage or are you using a Selenium web driver (has this built in)

Comment: Yes. I have that part working, that is, use selenium and visit a page and then capture a screenshot.

Comment: Ok, do you mind adding some of the code you currently have to your question?

Comment: @KalebaKBKeitshokile I edited the question.  But, I think I have it figured out.  I can get the screen shot of the site and then use the smtp method with python to send an email of that image.  Should work out.

Comment: That's what  I was thinking, if your solution works, please post it below as an answer so that people In the future can refer to your question

Answer (score 0):

Rough solution:

- use https://wkhtmltopdf.org/ to capture web page as a jpeg or png
- save the jpeg or png to somewhere your sms software can send it
- have the sms software send the jpeg/png to the mobile number you want

Kinda depends if you have the screenshot or not. Web page is html aka not image. A web browser renders it to screen. You need SW that will transform it to jpeg/png. PIL does image manipulation but that won't work on html.